# Problema con bloque if

Tags: python, condiciones, sqlite

¿Me podrían ayudar a ver qué condición poner en el ultimo bloque de código donde se encuentra `if` de esta clase?
Quiero que al usar el método `select_row_next2` y este devuelve un `None` sume uno a `index`.
Si uso `select_row_preview` y este devuelve un `None` quiero que reste y así poder acceder al contenido de la base y ver los registros.
Estoy trabado con esto, si tienen otra sugerencia, también los escucho. Gracias, saludos.

```
class Busquedas:
    
    index = 0 # Uso variable de clase para retener el valor, si estuviese en __init__ se resetearia

    def __init__(self, tabla): #index cargo aca
        self._base = Base()
        self._cursor = self._base.conexion.cursor()
        self._tabla = tabla

    def select_row_next(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla}')

    def select_row_next2(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla} WHERE id={Busquedas.index+1}')
            
    def select_row_preview(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla} WHERE id={Busquedas.index-1}')
    
class A:
    ...
    def view_row(self, reg):
        register = self._cursor.fetchone()
        if register is not None:
            Busquedas.index = register[0] 
            return register
        else:
            if ...: # Qué debería poner en esta condición?
                Busquedas.index = Busquedas.index + 1
            else:
                Busquedas.index = Busquedas.index - 1
```

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. La parte de que te digamos la condición que poner en el if si se entiende. Por cierto, no es necesario usar el primer else ya que si entra en el `if`, el `return` termina la función.

Comment: Hola q tal, gracias por contestar y disculpen si no esta claro, tratare de ser mas especifico o claro. El tema seria así, estas funciones se llaman al presionar botones de siguiente y anterior en un formulario tkinter que tengo, el problema es que en los registros que se guardan en la base (hecha con sqlite) y que tiene un id consecutivo se muestran bien.

Comment: El PROBLEMA es cando en los registros hay ids no consecutivos, pro ej de 14 al 16, en ese salto se genera un None ya que no hay resultado y para solucionar eso puse el bloque if y así sumar o restar valor a index, el tema es que aquí no se cual condición poner para q el programa reconozca que en caso de presionar el botón siguiente sume y haga lo contrario en caso de presionar el botón anterior, porque de momento lo que hace con las condiciones que le puse(que ya las saque del código) es entrar siempre en la primer parte y sumar al id sin importar cual boton se presione , siguente o anterior..

Comment: El problema es que estás iterando sobre id inventados... en vez de iterar sobre ids inventados consecutivos, haz una primera llamada que te obtenga todos los ID sobre los que luego iteras. De esa manera no te inventas ningún id y no necesitas controlar nada de manera extraña.

Comment: ok gracias lo voy a intentar, saludos